# C# extension method only working with an instance of the class. Any way around it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods

As far as I know, C# only let us use extension methods with an instance of a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string GetStuff()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

public static class MyClassExtension
{
    public static string GetOtherStuff(this MyClass myClass)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MyClass.GetStuff();
MyClass.GetOtherStuff();       // Cannot resolve symbol 'GetOtherStuff'
new MyClass().GetOtherStuff(); // This works
```

However, I noticed that the MVC framework allows me to extend the HtmlHelpers in such a way that I can use my extension methods without creating any instance of a class. For example, if I create an extension method for `HtmlHelper` like this:

```
public static string MyHtmlHelper(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    return string.Empty;
}
```

I can use it in a Razor View like this:

```
@Html.MyHtmlHelper() // no need to instantiate a class
```

I would really like to achieve the same result with my `MyClass`, so I can do:

```
MyClass.GetOtherStuff()
```

How could I do that?

Comment: What makes you think `@Html` isn't an instance of a class?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How can I achieve that result so I don't have to use the notation new MyClass()?

Comment: In a Razor view, `@Html` is [this property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage.html(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Html) of the base class. If you're willing to impose a base-class requirement at the point of usage (as Razor does) then you can achieve this.

Comment: If this is your class can you not just add a static method to it?

Comment: @Scrobi no because we are building a modular app in which each module should add to the same base class its own methods.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Please do you have a link that explains your proposed concept

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot create a C# extension method that does not require an instance of the class. ([Here's a longer explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/866932/590382))

**Option #1**

However, you *can* create your extension methods that hang off the existing `@Html`/`HtmlHelper` in Razor views.

```cs
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string GetOtherStuff(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        return "other stuff";
    }
}
```

**Option #2**

It's also possible to create your own equivalent of `HtmlHelper`, so that you can then access it in just the same way from a `.cshtml` Razor view.

Define an empty class to extend with your extension methods:

```cs
public class MyCustomHelper
{
    // Can just be an empty class.
}

public static class MyCustomHelperExtensions
{
    public string GetStuff(this MyCustomHelper helper)
    {
        return "stuff";
    }
}

public static class MyOtherCustomHelperExtensions
{
    public string GetOtherStuff(this MyCustomHelper helper)
    {
        return "other stuff";
    }
}
```

The `HtmlHelper` instance is accessed from [a property on WebViewPage.cs](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/WebViewPage.cs#L26). You can extend `WebViewPage` with your own class and [then configure Razor to use that instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195555/implement-a-custom-mvc-base-view-page):

```cs
public class BaseViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    private MyCustomHelper _foo;

    public MyCustomHelper Foo
    {
        get
        {
            if (_foo == null)
            {
                _foo = new MyCustomHelper();
            }

            return _foo;
        }
        set
        {
            _foo = value;
        }
    }
}

public class BaseViewPage : WebViewPage
{
    private MyCustomHelper _foo;

    public MyCustomHelper Foo
    {
        get
        {
            if (_foo == null)
            {
                _foo = new MyCustomHelper();
            }

            return _foo;
        }
        set
        {
            _foo = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And then access from a Razor view like this:

```
<div>
    @Foo.GetOtherStuff()
</div>
```

Comment: But I'm not asking how to extend HtmlHelper. If you read my question you'll see that I already did that. I'm asking how to obtain a similar result with my own custom c# class, so that I can add extension methods to it without using the notation `new MyClass()`. I'd like the extension methods to be usable like this: `MyClass.MyExtensionMethod()`.

Comment: @tocqueville, I'm sorry, but as I said in the first line of my answer, you cannot create an extension method without having an instance of a class _somewhere_. [This answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/866932/590382) explains why. You can, however, achieve the same effect from the point-of-view of your Razor views using the "Option #2" I added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to add static methods to your class. This [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551452/how-to-create-a-method-at-runtime-using-reflection-emit) might give you some idea about using reflection to add methods.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, what about it:

```
public class Foo {
    public static T Bar<T>(this T obj) where T : class {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot add static methods to a class via extension methods...

Because it doesn't make sense. What you are proposing is no different that creating a second static class with your new helper method. Just do that.

You want to do this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string GetStuff()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    // Extension method.
    public static string GetOtherStuff()
    {
        // cannot use any non-public members of MyClass
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
MyClass.GetStuff();
MyClass.GetOtherStuff();
```

**The above is not possible**. Also it would give you no advantage over just doing:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string GetStuff()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

public class MyClassExtension
{
    public static string GetOtherStuff()
    {
       // also cannot use any non-public members of MyClass
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
MyClass.GetStuff();
MyClassExtension.GetOtherStuff();
```

One final alternative is create a subclass:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string GetStuff()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

public class MyClassExtension : MyClass
{
    public static string GetOtherStuff()
    {
       // also cannot use any non-public members of MyClass
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
MyClassExtension.GetStuff();
MyClassExtension.GetOtherStuff();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You're suggesting to create another class while I'm asking how to extend the first one without using the notation `new MyClass() `. There is a specific architectural reason why I need to extend the first class in that way.

Comment: @tocqueville Yes it does. You cannot add a static extension method. .NET doesn't support it. You can either change `MyClass` normally and get what you desire. Or you can create a second class like in my second example and call `MyClassExtension.GetOtherStuff()`. One final alternative is make `MyClassExtension : MyClass`...

Answer (score -1):

Could you just inherit from the BaseClass in each of your modules:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public static string SomeProperty { get; set; }

}

//Module 1
public class MyClassOne : MyBaseClass
{
    public static string MyFunction()
    {
        return SomeProperty + "MyClassOne";
    }
}

//Module 2
public class MyClassTwo : MyBaseClass
{
    public static string MyFunction()
    {
        return SomeProperty + "MyClassTwo";
    }
}
```

This would allow you to do:

```
MyClassOne.MyFunction()
```